# In select box option I want to search all the columns from mysql instead of one showing in dropdown option in php

Tags: php, mysql

From this dropdown I want to search all my columns from table

```
 <?php
foreach($db->selectboxoption($sql_fuel_type) as $data) 
{ 
     echo '<option value="'. $data["type_category_id"] .'">'. $data["type_category_name"] .'</option>'; 
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: no clarity in question.... need more description

Comment: don't misuse code snippet its purely for Html, CSS, javascript, jquery

Comment: Why even have a drop down in that case?

Comment: In dropdown list I can search only the one showing inside the option tag ...(<option> Name </option>) but i want to search with some other columns from my mysql table without showing that inside the option tag

Comment: Sorry I cant understand what you are exactly asking ? @chris85

Comment: No @AnandPandey

Comment: Why not just have a `checkbox` that says search all columns, then build your query dynamically, or use a full text index?

Comment: @AnandPandey Please keep comments in english, if that is useful content it would be good for future users to be able to read it... or possible even the first/last option be `all` and if the value is `all` do a different query.

Comment: If there is an mysql table with customer name and phone number...I have shown only the customer name inside the option tag(<option>customer name</option>) by searching their name we can choose our required customer... but i need to search customer name also with phone number option is it possible?

Comment: use data attribute in option tag so you can search with multiple column

Comment: Thanks @AnandPandey thats what my exact que but can you show me one llittle example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give here example for the data-attribute. You have to add your logic for searching the phone, it is a basic idea for select the option from the search match.

PHP code:

```
<select id="selectuser">
    <?php 
    foreach($db->selectboxoption($sql_fuel_type) as $data){ 
    echo '<option data-phone="'.$data["phone_no"].'" value="'.$data["type_category_id"].'">'.$data["type_category_name"] .'</option>'; 
    } 
    ?>    
</select>
```

Jquery code:

```
// your logic here(if phone no is match with your search phone)
$('#selectuser').find("option").filter(function() {
     return $(this).text() == $(this).data('phone');  
}).attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: sir is it possible to serach dropdown options through data-attribute values?

Comment: Yes it is possible by jquery